# Fun with JSTL looping and int conversion into a char

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

What I need is a jsp using jstl that will output column labels as Chars (A, B, C...) instead of ints (1, 2, 3...) and just for fun, when the int is greater than 26 it should output AA, AB, AC...oh and when the int is greater than 52 it should be BA, BB, BC... and on and on.

Exactly how excel would label columns.

What I have now works fine until the index hits 27.

```
<c:forEach var="column" items="${vo.dataFormat.columns}" varStatus="loopStatus">
    <div class="columnLabel">&#${loopStatus.index + 65};</div>
</c:forEach>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to do this logic in the controller, and pass the result to a dumb JSP?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean AA, AB, AC... for ints greater than 26? and then AAA, AAB... for ints greater than...umm...702? just wondering :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial requirement, `..., X, Y, Z, AA, BB, CC, ...` , was easy:

```
<c:forEach items="${vo.dataFormat.columns}" var="column" varStatus="loop">
    <div class="columnLabel">
        <c:forEach begin="1" end="${loop.index / 26 + 1}">
            &#${loop.index % 26 + 65};
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Your edited requirement, `..., X, Y, Z, AA, AB, AC, ...`, is however trickier. This works until ZZ only:

```
<c:forEach items="${vo.dataFormat.columns}" var="column" varStatus="loop">
    <div class="columnLabel">
        <c:set var="i" value="${fn:substringBefore(loop.index / 26, '.')}" />
        <c:if test="${i > 0}">
            &#${i + 64};
        </c:if>
        &#${loop.index % 26 + 65};
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

As there's no `while` loop in JSTL, getting from ZZ to AAA and so on isn't possible with clean code.

Comment: Thanks Balus as always you're great!